# PC Settings is disabled

Tags: windows-8

I've installed Windows 8 and I cannot change anything in PC Settings. Everything is grayed out/disabled. How can I enable this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot that highlights the problem?  Are you using a `Local` or `Microsoft Account`

Comment: Local user, member of Administrators

Comment: Is your windows activated ?

Comment: on one PC it is activated and on another it is not (same problem on both machines)

Comment: Legal activation ? if you activated using a non-genuine activator, it might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the activation it looks that the option enabled

Comment: I thought you were having the same problem even in the activated OS (as per your comment above)?

Comment: i'll try to re-install and reactivate OS on the other PC

Answer (score 0):

If it's just on the Personalize screen, you need to activate Windows.

Once Windows detects it's not genuinely activated, it goes into Reduced Functionality mode, which just annoys you by turning off wallpaper, personalization settings, and it restarts every hour or two.